# Thinktecture Identity Server - setup external identity providers

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, facebook-apps, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm following Brock's tutorial on OAuth2 identity providers: [OAuth2 in Thinktecture IdentityServer : OAuth2 identity providers](http://brockallen.com/2012/11/04/oauth2-in-thinktecture-identityserver-oauth2-identity-providers/) and I'm having problems trying to setup each provider details. I'm trying to use google and facebook.

Google: What I've done is. I've created new project, within which I've gone to APIs & auth > Credentials > Create New Client ID and then chose "Web Application" option. On "Client ID for web application" panel in "Javascript Origins" section I have pasted base URL of my IdSrv (`https://somename`). I have copied Client ID and Client secret and pasted both into appropriate sections in IdSrv identity provider shown in tutorial. When I run the application I get the invalid_request error from Google saying Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: `https://somename/idsrv/issue/hrd/oauth2callback`

In case of Facebook, I've created new App, and was trying to set "Site URL" in basic settings to `https://somename`, but got an alert saying "must be a URL with a valid domain." which I believe is essentially the same as what the Google error message is saying

My question is: How can I deploy a test version of my IdSrv then? I just want a quick and simple environment for testing purposes for now. Am running the IdSrv in my local IIS, was following Dominick installation tutorial video [Thinktecture IdentityServer v2 Tutorial: Installation](http://vimeo.com/51088126)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we setup IdentityServer for local testing we configure it to run under IIS with a custom host name and then setup a entry in the local hosts file. To google this should appear as a public URL.

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach is to use one of the localhost DNS services that exist.

For example, `whatever.vcap.me` resolves to **127.0.0.1** as does `production.vcap.me`, `staging.vcap.me` and `development.vcap.me`.